# Ajax with Rails 3 and jQuery - Called from JS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, fullcalendar

The goal is to render an edit form by calling some sort of `$.ajax` function in my javascript.

I am using [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) to display some events so I would like to implement something that allows the user to click on an event and render our existing edit form somewhere on the page.

So this is where I'm looking to do it:

```
// the javascript
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/course_offerings/'+calEvent.id+'/edit',
  });
},
```

`eventClick` is essentially a callback after you click an event :)

`calEvent.id` is a `course_offering` id
So unfortunately I don't have access to the nice `:remote => 'true'` options for setting up links.

Here's a few snippits of code:

```
# controller edit function
@course_offering = CourseOffering.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end

# edit.js.erb, quickedit is the div where I want the form to render
$('#quickedit').append('hi');
```

Is this the correct way to go about this? I really want to start as simple as possible with the ajax calls, I've been reading some examples and they get pretty complex.

Also the requirements for a jquery `$.ajax` call in a Rails environment are pretty much a mystery to me.

**Edit 1:**

Sooo close

I tried the following:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'script',
    url: "/course_offerings/1/edit"
});
```

And in chrome's debugger I got:

`http://localhost:3000/course_offerings/1/edit?_=1302199862022 500 (Internal Server Error)`

I haven't done any special header setup, so I think that might be the issue

**Edit 2**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial course_offerings/edit with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:js, :html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/home/emp/ror/smarssched/app/views", "/home/emp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/devise-1.1.5/app/views"):
    1: $("#quick_edit").html(<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'edit', :object => @course_offering) %>)
```

I switched the partial to edit after getting an error with `:partial => 'course_offering'`

To hopefully render the edit partial.

**Edit 3**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `formats' for nil:NilClass):
    1: $("#quick_edit").html(<%= escape_javascript(render :action => 'edit', :object => @course_offering) %>)
  app/views/course_offerings/edit.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_course_offerings_edit_js_erb__58426168_85487740_698365018'
  app/controllers/course_offerings_controller.rb:48:in `edit'

# Line 46-51 edit function
 def edit
@course_offering = CourseOffering.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.js
    end
 end
```

If I take the respond_to block out, it throws the same error.

Comment: can you give us the error from the actual rails app? ie. what is causing the 500

Comment: note my changes below, you're *probably* not rendering a partial, but an action.  partials are files that a prefixed with `_` and are only html fragments.

Comment: yup you were correct, after switching to a render :action the error goes away, but now we have a new one (edited question)

Comment: what does line 48 in your controller say?

Comment: posted the entire edit function

Comment: mmm ya that doesn't help, appears to be something in the view file itself, do you see a reference to `formats` anywhere?  Also, this code I know works for me in Rails2.  Not entirely sure if the rendering of a partial in js has changed since I know a lot of view related stuff changed in rails3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, to comment on your last sentence, there aren't any such requirements for making ajax calls between jquery and Rails.  They don't know about each other and they don't care.  As long as your url is correct and you're sending the correct data through when appropriate all is fine.  You just need to make sure that your request header is set properly.  jQuery by default makes an "intelligent guess" so I find it's always useful to specify what you want.  See the docs here, but in your case that means adding:

```
dataType: 'script'
```

to your ajax call

As for correct ways to do things, that looks about right and is pretty standard.  In your edit.js.erb you basically want to render out your view and append it to #quickedit.  Something like this should suffice:

```
$("#quickedit").html(<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'course_offering', :object => @course_offering) %>)
```

Note here that 'course_offering' would have to be a partial defined within the current view folder ie `/app/views/course_offerings/_course_offering.html.erb` assuming you're in the `course_offerings` controller.

In your case you're using 'edit' but I'm assuming edit isn't an partial (ie. html fragment) but rather a full action.  In this case try `render :action => 'edit'`

Comment: I added an edit to the question with some more stuff.  Thank you for the response. I think i need to setup the request header you mentioned.